# How to check Parental Controls with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, parental-control

I need to know if the current user is being managed by Mac OS X Parental Controls (more specifically, the app age restrictions) in order to block some contents of the app. How can I do that? Any of these will be enough.

Methods that can be achieved with Objective-C, but not necessarily using Objective-C, like bash commands or AppleScript commands, are also accepted.

**EDIT:** The app age restriction can be found here: https://ibb.co/mOZyww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure what you mean by

> app age restrictions

On macOS 10.13, I only see the option to restrict applications to a whitelist; I can't configure restrictions based on age.

Anyway, parental controls are stored in the local directory services, in the `mcx_attributes` attribute for the user in question.

(mcx refers to the old Managed Preference framework)

You can browse this via the UI using Directory Utility or via `dscl` (using the mcx plugin).

If you run `dscl`, you can then browse the directory services using `cd`, `ls`, etc.

For example, I can navigate to my testuser:

```
cd /Local/Default/Users/testuser
```

And then dump the parental controls with `mcxexport`

```
 -mcxexport .
```

This will give you the configured parental controls in XML format.

Check out `dscl . -mcxhelp` for more information.

**Updated**

Toggling the "Restrict: Apps to:" setting updates this preferences key:

```
<key>gamesLimit</key>
    <dict>
        <key>state</key>
        <string>always</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <integer>300</integer>
    </dict>
```

You would have to play around with it to figure out the corresponding values (e.g. 300 == Age 12+)

Comment: This is what I mean with 'app age restrictions': https://ibb.co/mOZyww Sixth option.

Comment: I tried using `cd /Local/Default/Users/testuser` replacing `testuser` with my user short name, and I received a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: I added the details of the key to my answer

Comment: Don't just `cd` into that path. Read my answer. Run `dscl`, which will allow you to browse directory services using commands like `cd`.

Comment: If you're looking for a one-liner, this form works for me: `dscl . -mcxexport /Users/testuser`

Comment: Your answer was the key to find what I was looking for, so thanks :) However, if someone wants to retrieve that value directly, he/she will have a more direct return using `dscl . mcxread /Users/testuser com.apple.iTunes gamesLimit`

Comment: By the way: `1000 => No limit`; `100 => 4+`; `200 => 9+`; `300 => 12+`; `600 => 17+`

Comment: Correcting myself, that command has a return easier to parse: `dscl . mcxexport /Users/testuser com.apple.iTunes gamesLimit`